# List sieve of eratosthenes

Tags: c++, arrays, list, sieve-of-eratosthenes

here a program that find a primary numbers in array from n to 2n. it works properly, but something must be otherwise:
In this program, the sieve is superimposed on the array: the elements are replaced by zeros. It should be wrong: no arrays. First, form a list of all the numbers one by one in the link list. Then remove from the list those links that contain multiples. At the end, print what is left. IDK how can i do this without arrays.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


struct node 
{
    int num;
    node* next, * prev; 
};

class List  // list
{
    node* head, * tail; 
public:
    List() :head(NULL), tail(NULL) {};
    void Print();
    void Add(int num);
};

void List::Print() //print list
{
    node* temp = head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        cout << temp->num << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void List::Add(int num)  //add to list
{
    node* temp = new node;
    temp->next = NULL;
    temp->num = num;
    if (head!=NULL)        
    {
        temp->prev = tail;
        tail->next = temp;
        tail = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp->prev = NULL;
        head = tail = temp;
    }
}



int main()
{

    List list;
    int n, num;
        cout << "Enter N :  "; cin >> n;
        n = abs(n);
    int* simp = new int[2 * n]; 
    // eratosphene's sieve
    for (int i = 0; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        simp[i] = i;
    }
    simp[1] = 0;
    for (int l = 2; l < 2 * n; l++) {
        if (simp[l] != 0) {
            for (int j = l * 2; j < 2 * n; j += l) {
                simp[j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = n; i < 2 * n; i++) {
        if (simp[i]) {
            num = simp[i];
            list.Add(num);
        }
    }
    cout << "Prime numbers of the list:\n";
    list.Print(); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No, nothing wrong with your program, but it's just lost some efficiency of the **sieve of eratosthenes**. The problem is your **sieve** **inner loop and outer loop** bounds should look as follows.

```
// upper bound = sqrt(2 * n) rather than (2 * n)

// l < (2 * n) -----> [ l*l < 2 * n is same as l < sqrt(2 * n) ]
for (int l = 2; l*l < 2 * n; l++) {
    if (simp[l] != 0) {

        // lower bound = l * l rather than (2 * l)
        for (int j = l * l; j < 2 * n; j += l) {
            simp[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

For the inner loop as `(2*l)` always **less** than `(l*l)` except case of 2 `(2 * l) = (l * l)` so no difference, but just useless **iterations**.

Answer (score 0):

Let's leave code aside for a moment and consider you would do this with a pen and paper: you would write down numbers 2 3 4 ... 2n and start off at "2" (outer loop). You would then (inner loop) mark (note here: NOT erase, only mark!) every second number beginning from 2*2=4.
Then you would return to the outer loop and consider "3" and mark every third number starting off at 3*2=6 (actually it would also be valid to start at 3^2=9).
This marking translates into setting the elements in the array to 0, and as a last step you would only consider the unmarked (i.e. non 0) elements.

In your approach you now want to erase the nodes from the linked list. Translating this into the pen-and-paper approach would be to erase the numbers from the paper.
Then you would start at "2" again, erase the multiples of 2, then go to "3" and erase the multiples of 3.
The important change is, that you can no longer just blindly erase every third number but you would actually have to look at the numbers and ask yourself: is that a multiple of 3?

Of course you could do that and you can also program that, but it wouldn't be the sieve of eratosthenes anymore. The strength of the algorithm is, that any multiples of a number are easily spotted by their index:
In your provided code, `simp[i] == 0 || simp[i] == i` holds all the time, i.e. a number is either marked or it it's index is actually the value itself. Therefore you do not have to look at the number and test whether it is dividable but you can just do the judgment based on its index.